# Not able to install Packages on Microsoft R open

Tags: r

I have installed Microsoft Open R on RHEL 7 with below method and now fails to  install packages .

Please help me to resolve the issue.

1.using wget got the rpm

2.yum install microsoft-r-open-mro-3.4.3.rpm

yum install microsoft-r-open-mkl-3.4.3.rpm

yum install microsoft-r-open-foreachiterators-3.4.3.rpm

3. R

Microsoft R Open 3.4.3

The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft

Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing (using 4 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-01-01.

4. When i try to install packages i am getting below error .

> install.packages("Boruta")
>   Installing package into â/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/libraries/RServerâ
>   (as âlibâ is unspecified)
>   curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01/src/contrib:
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status
Warning message:
package âBorutaâ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
>

Comment: have a good read on https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html. It says how to resolve that SSL handshake issue.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the link. Please clarify whether i need to download the cacert.pem from curl site or from https://mran.microsoft.com ?